# pandas rolling window: Boundary on start / end of series?

Tags: python, pandas

**Problem**

If I create a centered [`pandas.DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) window, any statistic calculated on it will contain `nan` at the start and end of the series (or only at start for `center=False`). This of course makes sense since the window isn't fully defined there.

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([2,1,3,2,4,5,6])
window = 5
print (s.rolling(window, center=True).median())

0    NaN
1    NaN
2    2.0
3    3.0
4    4.0
5    NaN
6    NaN
dtype: float64
```

**Question**

Is it possible to get a rolling window that retains its window width and just bounds at the start or end for the first / last few values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will effectively give identical values for the first / last values since the window is identical for them. So there's no need for a rolling window to bound at the start or end just to fill these numbers. Instead:

```
s2 = s.rolling(window, center=True).median()
s2.iloc[-window//2:] = s2.iloc[-window//2]
s2.iloc[:window//2] = s2.iloc[window//2]
print (s2)

0    2.0
1    2.0
2    2.0
3    3.0
4    4.0
5    4.0
6    4.0
dtype: float64
```

**Sidenote**

Another possibility to fill in values is setting `min_periods=window//2` in the given case (otherwise the default is the window width, which is why there appears `NaN` in the first place). The first and last values still have `3` valid values to consider. This may be a preferred strategy in many cases.

```
print (s.rolling(window, min_periods=(window//2), center=True).median())

0    2.0
1    2.0
2    2.0
3    3.0
4    4.0
5    4.5
6    5.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: The Sidenote is the actual answer. The window rolls over the boundary, but uses only the elements with values. So the first value is made from the window `| | |2|1|3|`, the second is made from the window `| |2|1|3|2|` and so on. This also works with mean, i. e. the result would be (2+1+3) / 3 for the first window. Note, you can simply use `min_periods=1`.